Polkit: is possible to avoid password request for users NOT present in group?
Observe this situation
lxcunpriv@nas:~$ id
uid=1001(lxcunpriv) gid=1001(lxcunpriv) gruppi=1001(lxcunpriv)

lxcunpriv@nas:~$ virsh -c qemu:///system list 
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.libvirt.unix.manage ====
System policy prevents management of local virtualized systems
Authenticating as: myuser
Password: 

If "lxcunpriv" know the password of "myuser" can stop the vm, or list, or access to it via console.
My question is, is possible to force authentication for libvirt group?
Must work as this
member of "libvirt" group = can access to vm
non-member of "libvirt" group = cannot access to vm even they know the other user password.
Is possible?

If you have Pokit newer than 0.106, you can express whatever condition you want using JavaScript
